# Angular 9 Ivy entryComponents conversion

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-ivy

```
@Component({
   selector: 'dynamic',
   template: '<ng-template *ngFor="let portal of portals" [cdkPortalOutlet]="portal"></ng-template>',
   // entryComponents before Ivy
   entryComponents: [Component1, Component2, Component3]
})
class DynamicComponent<T extends BaseComponentClass>() {
    portals: ComponentPortal<any>[] = [];

    constructor(@Inject(COMPONENTS_TOKEN) components: T[]) {
        // Something like this
        this.portals = components.map(c => new ComponentPortal(c));
    }
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        DynamicComponent
        Component1,
        Component2,
        Component3,
    ],
    imports: [PortalModule, CommonModule, MyOtherModule]
})
```

I have a component something like above that I create dynamically using `ComponentPortal` and `cdkPortalOutlet`. The `DynamicComponent` itself has many outlets and components that it creates. Previously with `entryComponents` I would list every component that could be loaded into the `DynamicComponents` outlets. This was working as expected, but now after upgrading to Ivy and removing deprecated `entryComponents`, this no longer works. I create `DynamicComponent` and it initializes fine, but components inside of `DynamicComponent` don't seem to be created and cause the entire `DynamicComponent` to fail its render. If I remove the outlets in `DynamicComponent` then everything else in `DynamicComponent`renders fine.

My thoughts are that the dependency components of DynamicComponent are not resolved when creating it. The dependency components are not used in any other angular components. Am I missing something on how to convert old entryComponent behaviour to work with Ivy?

EDIT:
`"buildOptimizer": false` fixes it but ideally want to keep this on.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `entryComponents` array in your `DynamicComponent` class where you list the components that are not referenced elsewhere, e.g.:

```
class DynamicComponent<T extends BaseComponentClass>() {
    entryComponents = [Component1, Component2, Component3];
    ...
```

The fact that the components are referenced will prevent them from being tree shaken, even though the variable is not used for anything. See an interesting discussion about this kind of problem and possible solution at this [Angular GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/33715#issuecomment-617606494).

Answer (score 0):

A component can also be bootstrapped imperatively in the module's ngDoBootstrap() method. The @NgModule.bootstrap property tells the compiler that this is an entry component and it should generate code to bootstrap the application with this component.

The following is an example of specifying a bootstrapped component, AppComponent, in a basic app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] // <-- bootstrapped entry component
})
```

https://angular.io/guide/entry-components